# Entity Framework N- Layer no binding with datagridview

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview, n-layer

I have a layer of Data like this to bring me all Admins:

```
  public List<Datos_Admin> SelectAllAdmin() 
    {
        return (from u in contexto.Datos_Admin select u).ToList() ;
    }
```

In my layer of Entities have this:

```
public class EDatos_Admin
{
    public int Id_Admin { get; set; }
    public string User_Name { get; set; }
    public char Password { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Ap_Paterno { get; set; }
    public string Ap_Materno { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha_Alta { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha_Modificacion { get; set; }
    public int UserAdmin_Modificacion { get; set; }
    public bool Activo { get; set; }

    public EDatos_Admin(int Id_Admin, string User_Name, char Password, string Nombre, string Ap_Paterno, string Ap_Materno, DateTime Fecha_Alta, DateTime Fecha_Modificacion, int UserAdmin_Modificacion, bool Activo)
    {
        this.Id_Admin = Id_Admin;
        this.User_Name = User_Name;
        this.Password = Password;
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
        this.Ap_Paterno = Ap_Paterno;
        this.Ap_Materno = Ap_Materno;
        this.Fecha_Alta = Fecha_Alta;
        this.Fecha_Modificacion = Fecha_Modificacion;
        this.UserAdmin_Modificacion = UserAdmin_Modificacion;
        this.Activo = Activo;

    }

    public EDatos_Admin()
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
    }
}
```

And in my Bussines layer have this:

```
    public EDatos_Admin SeleccionaAllDatos_Admin()
    {

        foreach (var n in contexto.SelectAllAdmin())
        {
            listDatosAdmin = new EDatos_Admin()
            {
               Id_Admin = n.Id_Admin,
               User_Name = n.User_Name,

            };

        }
        return listDatosAdmin;

    }
```

In the datagridview only I want show me Id_Admin and User_Name but it doesn't. And when I review in debugging I can see the data but the datagridview doesn't work.

And I call the method SeleccionaAllDatos_Admin in my Bussines layer like this in the load form

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = new NDatos_Admin().SeleccionaAllDatos_Admin();
```

How can fixed?
Thanks

Comment: Could you rephrase "but it doesn't but the method in debuging bring the information"?

Comment: Well in debugging bring the information but in the datagridview don't show me nothing.

Comment: That's because debugging forces query execution. You should probably add a `ToList()`.

Comment: you can show me an example

Comment: Taking a closer look, you're not building a list at all in the loop. You're creating `listDatosAdmin` objects of which only the last one is returned. Maybe you should create working code first (e.g. `EDatos_Admin SeleccionaAllDatos_Admin()` has no return type) and then update your question.

Comment: well not work but thanks